# converting list of numbers into list of strings appending some strings

Tags: python

This question is related to converting list of numbers into list of strings appending some strings.

How to convert the source below :

```
source = list (range (1,4))
```

Into the result below:

```
result = ('a1', 'a2', 'a3')
```

Comment: based on the title which mentions 'some strings' as apposed to the example, if you needed to join different string to different numbers you could use zip. `[a + str(b) for a, b in zip('abc', range(1, 4))]`

Answer (score 7):

You can either use *List Comprehension*:

```
# In Python 2, range() returns a `list`. So, you don't need to wrap it in list()
# In Python 3, however, range() returns an iterator. You would need to wrap 
# it in `list()`. You can choose accordingly. I infer Python 3 from your code.

>>> source = list(range(1, 4))
>>> result = ['a' + str(v) for v in source]
>>> result
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

or [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) with [`lambda`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
>>> map(lambda x: 'a' + str(x), source)
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

Comment: Please remove the outer `list()`. `range()` returns a list.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke. Not in Python 3, which is what I assume OP is using, as per his code. Still I'll add a note of it.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I should get used to Python 3.

Comment: Then you could also add a note that he does not need the `source`, just put `range(1, 4)` into the LC.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke. Well, may be OP wants to use `source` somewhere else. Anyway, he'll gradually figure it out. So, I'll leave that to him as homework. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> source = list(range(1,4))
>>> result = ['a{}'.format(x) for x in source]
>>> result
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> source = list(range(1,4))
>>> ['a%s' % str(number) for number in source]
['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
source = list(range(1,4))
result = []
for i in source:
    result.append('a'+str(i))
```

use a for loop to append them with the 'a'